# MySQL Join Table in Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

I'm new in PHP and CodeIgniter. I have a problem.

Here is what my database looks like:

Table 1 :

```
---------------------------------------------
| id_table1 | data_table1_1 | data_table1_2 |
---------------------------------------------
```

Table 2 :

```
---------------------------------------------------------
| id_table2 | id_table1 | data_table2_1 | data_table2_2 |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

Table 3 :

```
---------------------------------------------------------
| id_table3 | id_table2 | data_table3_1 | data_table3_2 |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm selecting my table data from Table 3, and i join with Table 2. My question is, how can i get the data from Table 1 with other ways or join to get data_table1_1 without adding id_table1 in Table 3 ? Thankyou :)

Comment: Can you show us some sample data the tables contain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope this will work for you

```
$sql = "SELECT * from table 3 
        JOIN table 2 ON table 2.id = table 3.id
        JOIN table 1 on table 1.id = table 2.id
        ";
$res = $this->db->query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without data information gets difficult.
You can do it:

```php
$this->db->select()
     ->from('table3')
     ->join('table2', 'table3.id_table2 = table2.id_table2', 'INNER')
     ->join('table1', 'table2.id_table1 = table1.id_table1', 'INNER')
     ->get()
     ->result_array();
```

Comment: i have some few error, but i had found answer from another people. Thank you for helped me :)